# Sed Replacing multiple words in a subpattern

Tags: ubuntu, unix, sed

I have a word
word- which I want to replace with
^word how do I do this with sed?

Comment: Welcome to SO, always try to show your efforts in order to fix your problem in your post with code tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's/word-/\^word/g' file_name.txt
```

[Reference](https://linuxconfig.org/learning-linux-commands-sed):Subsitute `'s'` word- with ^word globally `'g'` in file_name.txt and save it `'-i'` to the original file.

Comment: OP wants the carrot in front the word:  `sed 's/word-/\^word/'`

Comment: Ah I see, Sorry I missed the "carrot".Thanks for pointing that the vegetable needs to be in front of the word.

Comment: You don't have to escape `^` in the substitution string, it's not special there.

Comment: Ugh, I just love spellcheckers; yes, caret.